# Block a domain for every Top Level Domain in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm looking for a solution to the match pattern rules for making a Google Chrome Extension - I'm trying to block websites such as Pinterest, the problem is that Pinterest has a million TLDs and rather than write out...

`"*://pinterest.com/*, *://pinterest.se/*, *://pinterest.co.uk/*..` etc Forever

I'm trying to block all of Pinterest's Top Level Domains.

Using `"*://pinterest.*/*"` or `"*://*.pinterest.*/*"`  does not work.

```
var blockedUrls = [ "*://*.pinterest.se/*, *://*.pinterest.com/*"];


var host = "https://www.google.com"


chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) {
     return {redirectUrl: host };
},
{
    urls:blockedUrls,

    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
},
["blocking"]
);
```

The above code works.
Anyone got any idea how to do this, any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.
Many Thanks.

Comment: `*://*.pinterest.*/*`???

Comment: I wish! That causes an error, I'll make this more clear in my question.

Comment: causes "an error" ? Please share what the error is you get, and please share the code that throws the error instead of (or in addition to) the code that works.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't cause an error, it just doesn't work. Which is an error but not an ''error"

Comment: Have you tried using `"<all_urls>"` and then checking the url manually (maybe with RegExp) inside your listener function?

Comment: Thank You, that's amazing and so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) you have this example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
          return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("://www.evil.com/") != -1};
        },
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["blocking"]);
```

Just change `www.evil.com/` by `pinterest.` and it will block all `pinterest.*` pages. If you want to block other subdomains like `m.pinterest.com` or `images.pinterest.com` (I don't know if these even exist) you could use RegExp.